# Can not validate empty input field using c# asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I can not validate for empty input field using c# asp.net. Actually I have two input field. I need to display validation message for blank input field. I have done some coding. When I am clicking on submit button without giving any input, I am getting the error message for first input filed `i.e., Name field can not be blank` and one red color border on that input field. When I am giving any input to first input field and again clicking on submit button the error message for second input field is coming but problem is border color is showing red in first input field which should not come. I am explaining my code below.

> index.aspx:

```
<div class="widget-title">Doctor Registration <span id="validationMessage" runat="server" ></span></div>
<div class="row doctorlist-form">
    <div class="col-md-6 bmargindiv1">
        <label for="doctorname" accesskey="N"><span class="required">*</span> Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-2 padding-zero">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="txtdoctorprefix" name="doctorname" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Dr." Selected="True" Text="Dr."></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Mr." Text="Mr."></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Mrs." Text="Mrs."></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10 padding-zero"><asp:TextBox ID="txtDoctorName" runat="server" oninput="detectName('dName');" ></asp:TextBox></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 bmargindiv1">
        <label for="gender" accesskey="G"><span class="required">*</span> Gender</label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="txtGender" name="grnder" runat="server" onchange="selectGender('gender');">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select your Gender" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="male" ></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="female"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 bmargindiv1">
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" class="button" ID="doctorDetails" OnClick="doctorDetails_Click" />
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function detectName(nameid) {
         var type = nameid;
         console.log(type);
         switch (type) {
             case 'dName':
                 $('#<%=txtDoctorName.ClientID %>').css('border-color', '#e3e3e3');
                 $('#<%=validationMessage.ClientID %>').empty();
                 break;
         }
     }
     function selectGender(type) {
         var type = type;
         switch (type) {
             case 'gender':
                 $('#<%=txtGender.ClientID %>').css('border-color', '#e3e3e3');
                 $('#<%=validationMessage.ClientID %>').empty();
                 break;
         }
     }
</script>
```

> index.aspx.cs:

```
protected void doctorDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Response.Write(txtDoctorName.Text.Trim().Length);
    if (txtDoctorName.Text.Trim().Length == 0 )
    {
        validationMessage.InnerText = "Name field can not be blank.";
        validationMessage.Style.Add("color", "red");
        txtDoctorName.Focus();
        txtDoctorName.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        return;
    }
    if (txtGender.SelectedIndex==0)
    {
        validationMessage.InnerText = "Gender field can not be blank.";
        validationMessage.Style.Add("color", "red");
        txtGender.Focus();
        txtGender.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        return;
    }
}
```

My problem is when total field is blank and I am clicking on submit button the error message is coming properly but at the same time when I am giving some input to 1st text field and again clicking on submit button the 1st if statement is also executing along with the second if statement which should not happen. In this case only second if statement should execute. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: have you used the debugger to step through the `doctorDetails_Click` event? also have you thought about using the `IsNullOrEmpty` to check the input of the txtDoctorName.Text field

Comment: @ MethodMan : i have also tested using `IsNullOrEmpty` but also issue was there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend using the ASP.NET validation controls. For example:

**ASPX Page**

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="vs" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Default" />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtDoctorName" runat="server" />

<asp:CustomValidator 
    ID="cv" 
    runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txtDoctorName"
    ValidateEmptyText="true"
    Text="*" 
    OnServerValidate="ValidateRequired"
    ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid Doctor Name."
    ValidationGroup="Default" />
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void SubmitOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsValid) return;
    ...
}

protected void ValidateRequired(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Value.Trim());
}
```

The ValidationSummary will give you a nice listing of all validation errors, rather than just one at a time.

If you're going to continue with this method, to fix the red border on the first text box not going away, you will need to reset the border color each time the button is clicked:

```
protected void doctorDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Clear all properties each time the button is clicked
    validationMessage.InnerText = string.Empty;
    txtDoctorName.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    txtGender.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

    if (txtDoctorName.Text.Trim().Length == 0 )
    {
    ...
}
```

You can start your project in Debug mode (F5), place a break point on the `doctorDetails_Click` method, and step through using F10 to see more details about what's going on.

Comment: @ GoatBreeder : i debugged my code. for second time click after enter some input to first field the pointer is not moving inside the first if statement but i can not know how the inner properties of 1st if statement are executing.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you asking how to execute the code in the  "if (txtDoctorName.Text.Trim().Length == 0)" block? If text was entered into txtDoctorName, this code will not execute. You'll need to leave txtDoctorName blank for this code to execute.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand, but I updated my answer. Just make sure that you're resetting all properties that are set in your "if" blocks. The .NET validation controls will handle all of this for you automatically.

Comment: @ GoatBreeder : Yes,your way is also useful.Can you help me to set the border-oclor as `#e3e3e3` please.

Comment: System.Drawing.Color col = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#e3e3e3");

Answer (score 0):

Since you set the color of the border explicitly on a control that is running at server (runat) - my strong hunch is that the ViewState is preserving these properities.

You can test that behaviour by reversing your code to check on the second input before the first, you may see that red border remains on the second now while (only) the first has failed validation

I agree with @GoatBreeder that you use buitin [validation controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx),